# How to get a forloop to iterate through asp.net validators

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, validation, webforms

I currently have an issue where I am trying to create a for loop within JavaScript to iterate through the ASP.net validators. The Issue I am having may sound a bit stupid (as I am rather new to JavaScript). But I keep getting an Error when I try to iterate through these. for the reason why I am doing this in JavaScript; I currently have 30 Validators when a drop-down list is selected the JavaScript hides a div tag and shows the other one. For this reason I need a for loop to cycle through the hidden Div's validators and disable them.

Apologies if this is a poor question, I've tried looking around for the past 30 minutes or so but was unable to find an answer. Below is the Current Code I have which is unable to work. The hide and Show work fine on its own unfortunately the for loop does not work correctly. Am I missing something obvious? Thanks again.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {


$('#Select1').on('change', function () {
     if (this.value == '1') {

                    $("#div1").show();
                    $("#div2").hide();

    for (i = 1; i < 15; i++) {
       var HiddenDiv1 = '<%=ValidatorName[i].ClientID%>';
       document.getElementById(HiddenDiv1).enabled = false;
       }
    }
});
});
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: It was an issue with the "var test" here was the details;


Compilation Error 
  Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

 Compiler Error Message: CS1525: Invalid expression term ')'

Comment: After updating the Expression Term (there was an extra '%') I am now having the error that  "The name 'ValidatorName' does not exist in the current context". Which indicates that '[i]' is not getting it's value through the forloop within the variable.

Answer (score 0):

So unless it's just missing from the snippet you posted, you never put the closing parenthesis in for the .ready function.  You have this:

```
$(document).ready(.......
```

But it's never closed

Comment: Oop's, Yes, I've missed a few things out on snippet just realised, will update now! (very new to this place so I got confused while formatting).